# Get next element with same class, regardless of its location in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, document

**Using jQuery**, if I have elements with the class `test` scattered throughout an HTML page, with no defined structure to indicate where they might be found, and if I have a variable called `currentItem` that contains `<div class="test">This is a test.</div>`, which is located halfway through the page, then how can I find the NEXT element with the `test` class that appears in the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.index()` and `.eq()` methods:

```
var $testCollection = $('.test'),
    i = $testCollection.index($yourElement);

var $next = $testCollection.eq(i + 1);
var $prev = $testCollection.eq(i - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.eq()` along with the `.index()` to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
var xElements = $('.test');
var xNextElement = xElements.eq(xElements.index(currentItem) + 1);
```

If you are searching for a next sibling then, try

```
var xNextElement = currentItem.nextAll('.test').first();
```